# Facebook iOS 14.0+ app install stuck at "Verifying Your Changes" even after SDK upgrade

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, ios14, facebook-ads

Trying to run an app install ads campaign through facebook; for the iOS 14 changes, it required me to update the SDK to 8.0+, I did, my app is currently on 9.0. What else does it need me to do? I have logged in on the latest/updated version many times, but still stuck ‍♂️

> SDK Update Required for iOS 14 Campaigns: To create an iOS 14 campaign, make sure your app has upgraded to version 8.0 or later of the Facebook SDK. (#2446693)

[image]
[image]
[image]